# how to get clippy-jquery activate using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

Just using [clippy-jquery](https://github.com/jimmysawczuk/clippy-jquery) and want to hide the main swf object but activate the functionality with another regular button. It has a function to update the text to by sent to the clipboard so I'm guessing that there must be a function to simulate the "click" event?

Comment: Just curious, why would you need that?

Comment: have you tried the straight forward `.click()` of jQuery??

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

A.Wolff: to change the image on the button I have to re-compile clippy which is a pain. If I can do it via another button I can style it would be easier.

ADi - I could but what clippy-jquery function do I can within that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used another clipboard library called [zeroClipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/) which worked and was customisable out of the box.